# Generic Quartz Job applied to different Classes and Schedules

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I have the following Quartz Job in a Net Core 6 project:

```
public class StrategyJob : IJob {

  private readonly Logger _logger;

  private readonly Strategy _strategy;

  public StrategyJob(Logger logger, Strategy strategy) {

    _logger = logger;
    _strategy = strategy;

  }
  
  public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context) {

    Result result = await strategy.Run();

    if (result.Code == ResultCode.Error)
      _logger.Error(result.ErrorMessage);

  } 

}
```

And the Quartz configuration is the following:

```
services.AddQuartz(x => {

  // Quartz configuration

  x.AddJob<StrategyJob>(y => y
    .WithIdentity("StrategyJob")
  );

  x.AddTrigger(y => y
    .WithIdentity("Minute10OfEveryHour")  
    .ForJob("StrategyJob")
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(10).RepeatForever())
  );

});
```

I need to make StrategyJob generic and apply it to different Strategies / Schedules:

```
Strategy fs = new FastStrategy(2, 4, 5); > Run it every second

Strategy ss = new SlowStrategy("xy", 2); > Run it every day

... More strategies, each with a schedule, but the job execution will be the same.
```

How to create a generic StrategyJob and apply it to different strategies / schedules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the strategy to the trigger's data. As long as you don't persist the scheduler in a database, you shouldn't be worried about the serialization of the trigger data.

```
var jobData = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "Strategy", new FastStrategy(...) }
}

x.AddTrigger(y => y
   .UsingJobData(new JobDataMap(jobData))
   . ...
```

You'll need to provide your own implementation of `IJobFactory`

```
public class JobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        var strategy = (Strategy)bundle.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Get("Strategy");
        return new StrategyJob(logger, strategy);
    }
}
```